# Possibility of achieving matrix of certain form as a product of $3 \times 3$ rotation matrices

Tags: matrices

Removing last row and last column of the result, is this matrix multiplication result possible?$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\cos \beta&-\sin \beta\\0&\sin \beta&\cos \beta\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}\cos \alpha&0&\sin \alpha\\0&1&0\\-\sin \alpha&0&\cos \alpha\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\cos \gamma&\sin \gamma\\0&-\sin \gamma&\cos \gamma\end{bmatrix}=$$

\begin{bmatrix}\cos \alpha&-\sin \alpha \sin \beta\\\sin \alpha \sin \gamma&\cos \beta \cos \gamma + \cos \alpha \sin \beta \sin \gamma\end{bmatrix}

Comment: You would get a $3\times3$ matrix as the answer

Comment: Your answer should be a 3 $\times$ 3 matrix, at the moment, you have a 2 $\times$ 2 matrix-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: I seem to get something more like this $$\begin{bmatrix}\cos \alpha& \cos \gamma -\sin \alpha \sin \gamma & \sin \gamma +\sin \alpha \cos \gamma \\ \cos  \beta  + \sin \alpha \sin \beta&\cos \alpha \sin \beta \sin \gamma &-\cos \alpha \sin \beta \cos \gamma \\ \sin  \beta  - \sin \alpha \cos \beta &-\cos \alpha\cos  \beta  \sin \gamma& \cos \alpha\cos  \beta \cos \gamma\end{bmatrix}$$ though I have not checked (and I have not removed a row or column)